# How to comment out edits in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, editing, markdown

But I have this post that I would like to upkeep [Now that I built Unity How do I Install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181474/now-that-i-built-unity-how-do-i-install-it)

Now every time that I edit it (for the future or in the future) I would Like to put some commented code in there so I can keep track of what I am doing.

Think of it like a changelog file in a debian package.

example:  Wed Oct  3 13:13:34 EDT 2012 
           *line 1:changed "teh" too "the"

but commented out. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you should not do it for personal tracking, there is no such way to do that on the site, but every time you edit something you are given the chance to add a comment to that edit

[image]

It can be later reviewed when you check the post's revisions by clicking on the **edited** link under the post

[image]

It will then show up on the [reversions list](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/4182/revisions) for that post

[image]